# How to display data from localstorage in html upon creation

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Im trying to display all the records that are in local storage.
Ive currently only managed to temporarily show records upon creation however they dissapear once refreshing the page.

```js
let tunings = [];
// example {id:1592304983049, title: 'Deadpool', year: 2015}

const addTuning = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault(); //to stop the form submitting
    let tuning = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        note1: document.getElementById('note1').value,
        note2: document.getElementById('note2').value,
        note3: document.getElementById('note3').value,
        note4: document.getElementById('note4').value,
        note5: document.getElementById('note5').value,
        note6: document.getElementById('note6').value
    }
    tunings.push(tuning);
    document.forms[0].reset();

    // to clear the form for the next entries
    //document.querySelector('form').reset();

    //display data 
    console.warn('added', {
        tunings
    });
    let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
    pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(tunings, '\t', 2);

    //saving to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('MyTuningList', JSON.stringify(tunings));
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addTuning);
});
```

This here displays data upon the creation of records however id like to grab every record in local storage and display it on the html page.

```js
//display data 
console.warn('added', { tunings });
let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(tunings, '\t', 2);
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code posted is the string *fetched* from local storage; all that code does is store the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to parse the data to get it in correct format.

This example relies on having the existence of a storage item called `tunings`

```
  const data = localStorage.getItem("tunings"); // Store the localstorage data in variable.

  // Set it to an empty array incase the storage is empty.
  if (!tunings || !tunings.length) {
    tunings = [];
  } else {
    tunings = JSON.parse(data); // Parse the data.
  }

  console.log(tunings); // Read the data for example.
```

Comment: Probably it would be good to check whether `data` is `null` *before* attempting to parse it, to prevent exceptions.